# Post-build line into makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, post-build-event

I would like several files to be copied from "folderA" to "folderB" automatically after each "make".

Does anyone know how to add a post-build line into the makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something like this to the end of your default `make` target (the first target in the makefile is always the default):

```
install folderA/{file1,file2,file3} folderA/*.foo folderB
```

If you want something more complicated, have a look at `man install` and `man cp`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would be an `install` target that is dependent on the build of the executable.  It typically uses the `cp` or `install` commands to copy the files.

[Here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_16.html)'s an example that illustrates this.